# How to delete an element to sort an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, do-while

I have to make a program that sorts an array into an ascending order and this is my code is to do this by finding the largest element and then assigning it to a second array and then deleting this element from the first array so I can find 2nd biggest one in that and then reassigning it to the second array's second position. Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int arr[x], arr1[x];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
          scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
          }

    do{
          int j, max = 0;
    for(j= 0; j < x; j++){
           if(arr[j] > max){
                     max = arr[j];
                     }
           }
    int k = 0;
    arr1[k] = max;
    k++;


          }while(sizeof(arr1) < sizeof(arr));

    int l;
    for(l = 0; l < x; l++){
          printf("%d\n", arr1[l]);
          getch();
          }
    }
```

But for some reason, it does not assign the second value of the second array.

Comment: Your program makes no sense. Take into acount that it could be simpler if you would sort the original array "in place" without using a second array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(arr1) < sizeof(arr)`  this will always evaluate to `FALSE`, as both the arrays are of *same* size, as indicated by your code.

That's why, the `do..while` loop is executed once only.

Also, as suggested in the answer provided by Daniofb,

```
int k = 0;
arr1[k] = max;
k++;
```

Is erroneous, as for every iteration of `do...while`, it will initialize `k` to `0`, thus, you'll end up overwriting `arr1[0]` element value every time . Please remove the `int k = 0;` from inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code

```
int k = 0;
arr1[k] = max;
k++;
```

will always set `arr1[0]` to `max` because you set `k = 0;` in the previous line.  I think you can use `qsort` function from `stdlib.h` to sort the array and then copy to the other array. Also Sourav Ghosh has it right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 2 array...
You can do the whole thing using just 1 array...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int arr[x];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    // k is for the k'th maximum value
    int k=x-1;
    do{
        int j, max_ind = 0; // max_ind = for k'th maximum value position
        for(j = 1; j <= k; j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[max_ind]){
                max_ind = j;
            }
        }
        // max_ind is the k'th '
        // Swapping with k'th position value
        int temp=arr[max_ind];
        arr[max_ind]=arr[k];
        arr[k]=temp;
        k--;
    }while(k>0);

    int l;
    for(l = 0; l < x; l++){
        printf("%d\n", arr[l]);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Here we are calculating `x'th maximum, x-1'th maximum, x-2'th maximum...` in each iteration.